# git responds with 403 - browser responds with 200

Tags: git, certificate

I'm trying to clone some projects from a git repository. Therefore I have a new certificate. I deleted my old certificate from the keychain access and imported the new one. Now I can still clone the old projects, as expected.

But when I try to clone one of the new repositories, I get a 403 error. The strange thing is, I actually can access the new repositories via the browser.

I tried to delete the certificate and re-import it, but no success.

Is git still using my old certificate? How can i find out if this is the case and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use proxy? BTW, are you trying to clone your repo by https or ssh?

Comment: I'm using https and no proxy

Comment: I solved the problem. I had to trust the certificate. Unfortunately Chrome didn't ask me if I want to trust, safari did.